# Create Django Application Settings Page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django app and am trying to make some specific model information changeable while the site is loaded. For example, I'd like to be able to change certain images on pages (banners and such) based on changes I make on the admin panel of Django. Additionally, I'd like to create a list of prepopulated migrations for my social media links that can be editable in a django admin page. My specific instance of this is for all of my social media links. I'd like to put my social media link in a model 'Facebook Url" = 'www.facebook.com/mypage. I would then like to put these links throughout the page using dot notation {{ project_settings.facebook.url }} for example. What is the easiest way to do this. I don't think I want to put the context in all of the views because I would have to do that for every page I want this to be available. In the case of my footer it is on every page. The background images are also on several different pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you're trying to do by creating `CustomText` and `CustomImage` models which look like the following:

```py
class CustomText(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField()
    plain_text = models.TextField("Plain/Markdown Text", blank=True)
    html_text = models.TextField("HTML Text", blank=True)
    auto_render = models.BooleanField("Render to HTML using Markdown (on save)", default=True)
    (... implementation of text->html omitted )

class CustomImage(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField("Description", null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Custom Image", upload_to="custom_images/", null=True, blank=True)
```

Then I added `myapp/templatetags/custom_resources.py`, which are a pair of template tags to retrieve the text or image from those models:

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from myapp.models import CustomImage, CustomText

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def custom_image(image_name):
    cimage = CustomImage.objects.filter(name=image_name).first()
    return cimage.image.url if cimage else "custom_image_%s_not_found" % image_name

@register.simple_tag
@mark_safe
def custom_text(text_name):
    text = CustomText.objects.filter(name=text_name).first()
    return text.html_text if text else "Custom text <%s> not found." % text_name
```

Finally, in your templates, load the templatetags, and then use the template tag with the appropriate slug for the resource you want.

```py
{% load custom_resources %}
...
{% custom_text 'custom_text_slug' %}
```